# passe an argument in add_action

Tags: php, wordpress

I want passe an argument in `add_action` in hook `wp_enqueue_scripts` for that I use this code :

```
$arg = "blue";

do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',$arg);

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myFn',21, "blue" );

public function myFn($color)
    {
       echo $color;

    }
```

but I get this an error in  this line: `do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',$arg);`

**Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called **incorrectly**. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `admin_enqueue_scripts`, or `login_enqueue_scripts` hooks.**,

what I miss ? any advice will be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. You'll need to find a different way to achieve your desired result.

add_action takes a total of 4 arguments and none of them allow you to pass anything into the function.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

It looks like you were confused by the last titled $accepted_args.

This allows you to determine how many arguments that are set in do_action your function will use, not define your own.